# What is a good storage for huge boolean(0/1)-only data

Tags: database, storage

I need to store trillions of random-accessed true/false bits. A natural way would be to have huge mem-mapped file(s), and build a service on top of it with some business logic (e.g. given an index, returns true/false). Is there something like that already in existance? Open Source only?  Thanks!

Comment: I would probably go with Redis GETBIT/SETBIT (including multiple bytes) with some logic on top. And of course http://redis.io/topics/partitioning *trillion* sounds huge, but it's 'just' one billion of 125-chars words.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any old database by chunking the data into smaller pieces. For example, use `binary(128)` in an RDBMS. The chunks must be big enough to hide the per-row overhead.